# Cross Correlation in numpy, with FFT - strange result?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I'm attempting to perform a cross-correlation of two images using numpy's FFT.

As far as I'm aware, we have that the cross-correlation of two images is equal to the inverseFFT of the multiplication of - Fourier transform of image A, and the complex conjugate of the Fourier transform of image B.

Thus, I have the following code:

```
img1 = cv2.imread("...jpg")
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
fft1 = numpy.fft.fft2(img1)

# I'm cross correlating the same image with itself
fft2 = fft1.copy()           
fft2 = numpy.conj(fft2)

#Element wise multiplication
result = fft1*fft2           
result_img = numpy.fft.ifft2(result)
result_img = numpy.abs(result_img) #Remove complex values

#Following images are attached
image_shifted = normalize(numpy.fft.fftshift(result_img))
image_nonshifted = normalize(result_img)
```

However, my results are rather strange. In order to obtain what I believe to be the actual correlation-result I have to fftshift the result. Here are some example images:

[Image, not shifted, you can see bright parts at each corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxFte.png)

[Image, shifted, looks much more like what an auto-correlation result should look like (centre point is maximal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aJu8.png)

I'm not sure if my code, or expected mathematics is wrong, but I can't quite figure out what's going on!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Better suited to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarkBorgerding Is there anyway I can explicitly move it there? Or should I delete this post and re-post there?

Comment: Is there any possibility you think that the origin should be in the center, but the library thinks the origin should be at the corner? e.g. you think the integers modulo 512 should be represented as [-256, 255], but it represents them as [0,511]?

Comment: You might be onto a good point here. If the first pixel [0,0] represents correlation with the images perfectly aligned, then it would make sense that [0,511] and [511,0] and [511,511] are also peaks - as the image would almost be aligned again. 
I'd assumed that the correlation result would "appear" as though pixel [0,0] represented the images correlated with Image A at origin [-255,-255] and image B at origin [0,0], but it could represent the images correlated with both at [0,0] (which makes more sense, in a way)

Answer (score 1):

FFTSHIFT shifts the zero-frequency component to the center of the signal. In this case the signal is an image. A good visual guide is [this](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/fftshift.html). If you expand the original output image, you will see something akin to this:

[image]

So all the FFTSHIFT is doing is centering around a zero frequency component. Mostly used for visualization purposes.Your original results are mathematically correct, but the axis just aren't centered where you expected them.